# What is wrong with my ternery expression in an Angular paragraph element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following one of three such widgets for progress notification and navigation. Each such bar displays progress for a task and when clicked, resumes that task.

```
<a href="" ng-click="GotToFnaPersonalInformation()">
    <p class="headingPurple">1. FNA2 <span>{{$scope.$parent.Fna.IsWaivered}}</span> {{$scope.$parent.Fna.IsWaivered === false ? '[This FNA has not been waivered.]' : ''}}</p>
    <div kendo-progress-bar="progressBar" k-min="0" k-max="100" ng-model="Fna.PercentageCompletion" class="fnaProgressBar"></div>
</a>
```

The two `{{}}` expressions are mine, and the anchor clock still does what it has always done properly. Now we have added an option to waive the FNA (Financial Needs Analysis), and I need to indicate it on the anchor bar. I thought real the ternary, i.e.

```
{{$scope.$parent.Fna.IsWaivered === false ? '[This FNA has not been waivered.]' : ''}}
```

Yet this does nothing. So I added a simple output expression,

```
 <span>{{$scope.$parent.Fna.IsWaivered}}</span>
```

And the latter doesn't do anything either. I've used binding expressions like this, different to some degree, with nary a problem. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Side note: the usual way to conditionally display text is `<span ng-show="$parent.Fna.IsWaivered">[This FNA has not been waivered.]</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drop `$scope` in your markup. Only the properties defined on scope is accessible to the view.

```
<a href="" ng-click="GotToFnaPersonalInformation()">
    <p class="headingPurple">1. FNA2 <span>{{$parent.Fna.IsWaivered}}</span> {{$parent.Fna.IsWaivered === false ? '[This FNA has not been waivered.]' : ''}}</p>
    <div kendo-progress-bar="progressBar" k-min="0" k-max="100" ng-model="Fna.PercentageCompletion" class="fnaProgressBar"></div>
</a>
```